# How to bind array of objects to formGroup and formarray using angular8

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Hi i have used reactive forms to bind array of objects to formArray, but here if i select any one item in one section and click of move to right/move to left, then the entire object has been moved from one section to other. But that functionality is working fine but i am unable to detect the chnages made from one section to other in the form.valuechanges(). Can anyone help me to detect the changes incase items has been moved from one section to other, and here i want the change detection but the functionality must work as it is, i mean the entire object to be moved from one section to other.

Thanks in advance.

I have working demo2 here, i want my previously posted demo1 to work like this demo2 with formarray working.
[DEMO 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lh5vzl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

DEMO:
[DEMO 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vd8gnv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

TS:

```
 private settingsGroupInfoForm() {
    if (!this.agentDetailsList) {
      // Add
     this.agentGroupViewInfoForm = this.FB.group({
          agentGroupView: this.FB.array(
            this.agentInView.map(x=>(x))
          ),
        })
    } else {
      // Edit
      if (this.agentDetailsList) {

       this.agentGroupViewInfoForm = this.FB.group({
          agentGroupView: this.FB.array(this.agentInView.map(x=>(x))),

      })
      }
      this.agentGroupViewInfoForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
          this.formEdit = true;
          console.log('agentGroupViewInfoForm', this.formEdit)
        })
      }
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="card-body overflow-auto py-0" *ngIf="agentGroupViewInfoForm"
            [formGroup]="agentGroupViewInfoForm">
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" *ngFor="let child of agentInView"   name="agentInGroup" formArrayName="agentGroupView">
                  <li class="list-group-item {{isInActiveItems(child) ? 'active' : ''}}" (click)="toggleActiveItem(child)">
                    {{child.value}}
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
```

Comment: https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/#formarray-in-the-template

Comment: This is a duplicate of your own question from 10 minutes ago. [How to assign dynamic array of objects to formgroup using angular8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60360363/how-to-assign-dynamic-array-of-objects-to-formgroup-using-angular8)

Comment: See also, your other questions about this https://stackoverflow.com/q/60321749/5367916 (2 days ago). https://stackoverflow.com/q/60303369/5367916 (4 days ago). My answer to your most recent question and the other answers and comments really should help you

Comment: yes but here there is no true or false option, here entire objects to be moved from one section to other, as it was of different concept, i posted

Comment: and yes with that answer only i was able to come till this step, and after this i had no way, but now trying with the controls concept as you shared few min back, will try and update you

Comment: There is a lot of documentation on this. Before my last answer, I had never created a dynamic array. I figured it out after reading the docs and one article. Angular is extremely well documented and constantly written about. Especially forms.

Comment: ya even i went through some blogs as well but it i came across static arrays and assigning values  but couldnt find anything which helps to my requirement, so i posted question thinking people like you may help me out

Comment: @Bhrungarajni It's hard to tell what you want to achieve. Demo 1 doesn't have anything to move. Can you create a much simpler demo that demonstrates the concept rather than your actual project.

Comment: @KurtHamilton sure i will create and update you

Comment: @Bhrungarajni I have a working demo where I can create controls dynamically and move them between forms. You mention you want to listen to changes - what do you want to list to exactly?

Comment: @Bhrungarajni And re-reading the question, I'm not 100% clear on what the requirements are. I think you need to add a clear list of objectives and expected output.

Comment: @KurtHamilton my problem is that,i have list of items getting from API, so now i want to move object from one section to other, so here without using form controls i was able to move the objects, but if i have removed or added an item to any one of the section from other, it has to say me there is someitem change

Comment: sorry for late response

Comment: like we have, this.form.valueChanges, there if there is change in the controls it detects the change so like that, i need so that i can  enable edit mode, if there is change detected

Comment: But it still doesn't give me a clear idea of what you want to achieve. It would be far better if you put a little bit of energy inot creating a **simple** working demo as the starting point, with a clear set of instructions about what you want to achieve

Comment: yes now i am creating the demo, will share in sometime and explain clearly what i want to achieve in that, thanks a lot

Comment: And by simple, I mean don't include anything that isn't essential. Styling isn't essential - only functionality is. Start off with the smallest amount of data that you can use to demonstrate your problem

Comment: @KurtHamilton i have created simple demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pi9djf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: here, i tried using formArrayname and formControlName but i couldnt load the values to the list, only first item gets added and rest items will be blank

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208592/discussion-between-kurt-hamilton-and-bhrungarajni).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Your problem

- You have 2 arrays of items of the same type
- You want to render a form array for each array
- You want to be able to move items between the arrays
- You want to be able to bind the form values back to the items on submit

### The design

As with pretty much every component-based problem in Angular, you should think about model first. Your model is king, and everything else is built around it.

In your demo, you are moving items between lists. You are updating your model and binding your HTML to that. Nothing wrong there - it's the right approach and works.

The added challenge here is that you also want to move form groups around as well. We still need to think model-first, but also think about moving related state at the same time we move items between lists.

In abstract terms, you currently have

```js
list1: [];
selected1: [];

list2: [];
selected2: [];
```

If you want to move items from 1 -> 2, your move method will remove any selected items from `items1` to `items2`. Simple.

Once you add forms, you will have a structure like this:

```js
list1: [];
selected1: [];
form1: FormGroup;
formArray1: FormArray;

list2: [];
selected2: [];
form2: FormGroup;
formArray2: FormArray;
```

And when you move items from 1 -> 2, you will continue to move items from `list1` to `list2`, but now you will also need to remove the related item from `formArray1` and add it to `formArray2`.

I am storing a reference to the form arrays to make them easier to work with later.

### Building the form

Working with form arrays is arguably the most complex part of this answer. The key with form arrays is that the HTML structure mimics the structure of the `FormGroup` object you build.

We can use `FormBuilder` to build a form from an array and bind to it like this:

component.ts

```js
buildForm() {
  this.model = [ 
    { value: 'a' }, { value: 'b' }, { value: 'c' }
  ];

  // create a form group for each item in the model
  const formGroups = this.model.map(x => this.formBuilder.group({
    value: this.formBuilder.control(x.value)
  }));

  // create a form array for the groups
  const formArray = this.formBuilder.array(formGroups);

  // create the top-level form
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    array: formArray
  });
}
```

And bind to it in the HTML like this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form1" (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <div formArrayName="array">
    <div *ngFor="let item of list1; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <input formControlName="value" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

This will generate an input for each item in the array, containing the values "a", "b", "c" respectively.

### Moving items

Moving items between arrays is a simple javascript problem. We need to `splice` the source array and `push` to the destination array.

To move items from list 1 to list 2:

```js
// move selected items from model 1
this.selected1.forEach(item => {
  const index = this.list1.indexOf(item);
  this.list1.splice(index, 1);
  this.list2.push(item);
});

this.selected1.length = 0;
```

This will loop through each selected item in list 1, splice it from the list, push it to list 2. It will then clear the selected items;

### Moving form groups

You will move form groups at the same time as you move items. It is similar in concept - you remove from one and add to the other. You built your form array from your model, so you know your indexes match.

```js
// move selected items from model 1
this.selected1.forEach(item => {
  const index = this.list1.indexOf(item);
  const formGroup: FormGroup = this.formArray1.controls[index] as FormGroup;

  this.list1.splice(index, 1);

  // move between form arrays
  this.formArray1.removeAt(index);
  this.formArray2.push(formGroup);

  this.list2.push(item);
});
```

Notice here how there are 2 lines to move between form arrays that look similar to the 2 lines used to move between regular arrays.

`formArray.removeAt(index)` and `formArray.push(formGroup)` are doing the moving. The difference with the form array is that we need to get a reference to it first using `this.formArray1.controls[index] as FormGroup;`.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3cwnsv

**Caution**

In this design the order in which you remove from and add to the arrays and forms is important. You are binding your HTML to both your arrays and your form. You are creating the array of inputs by looping over your array, and binding each item to the `i`th group in the form array. If you remove from the form first, you will now have `n` items in the array and `n - 1` items in your form array. You will have an error when trying to bind to an undefined `n`th form group.

You are now performing a transaction with multiple operations.

Aside from ensuring you remove and add in the correct order, one way around this is to use `OnPush` change detection. Read up on this, as it's a good strategy for all but the simplest apps.

### Next steps

I kept my demo simple for the purposes of the answer. It isn't particularly scalable or reusable as it stands. There is a lot of repeated code and bad naming to try and avoid getting distracted by nested components and property names that relate to your application.

In reality you would probably want to create a child component that is responsible for a lot of the code that I have duplicated. The design of that is definitely out of scope for this question.

Comment: Must say this is a quality answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm, its been a week i was trying on this, thank you soo much, your answer is like inspiration to me, it is prompting me to learn more about these topics.

Comment: @Bhrungarajni Your task is not simple - there are a lot of moving parts. It's obviously important to learn what's going on technically here, but try and think about the design in simple terms too. Also breaking down the requirements into simple functional steps is essential if you are to define the problem to yourself or anyone else. Good luck :)

Comment: @Bhrungarajni I forgot to add this to my answer. If you're not using OnPush change detection, the order in which you move items around is important. I'll explain why in the edit I'm about to make

Comment: @KurtHamilton sure, to be very frank i am getting more interest to learn on these concepts

Comment: @KurtHamilton i need your help to solve this, could you please help me out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60963991/how-to-avoid-same-value-repeating-in-the-formcontrolname-using-angular8