# how to detect the boolValue and enable the input field from formArray using angular8

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

i have formArray which is getting binded by the dynamic array of objects coming from API. if the boolValue is true then the input field must be enabled or it must be disabled. but here i am able to bind the values but not able to enable/disable the input fields based on boolValue.

Demo:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmhwjy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

HTML:

```
 <div formArrayName="array">
    <div class="col" *ngFor="let value of values;let i = index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <div class="custom-control custom-switch mb-3">        
          <label class="custom-control-label">
            <input type="checkbox" formControlName="boolValue" (click)="selectedbool(i)" /> 
            {{value.label}}
          </label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" formControlName="datetime" (click)="dateRestriction(i)" class="onlyDateTime"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Ts:

```
this.form = this.FB.group({
          array: this.FB.array(
            this.values.map(x => this.FB.group({
              boolValue: this.FB.control(x.boolValue),
              datetime: this.FB.control(x.datetime)
            }))
          )
        }); 



values =  [ 
{
      id: 17,
      value: null,
      label: "Inactive From",
      datetime: null,
      boolValue: false
    },
    {
      id: 20,
      value: null,
      label: "No Access to System From",
      datetime: null,
      boolValue: false
    },
    {
      id: 23,
      value: null,
      label: "Restrict New Business",
      datetime: null,
      boolValue: true
    }];
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kgmfk9

Comment: thanks for response, if the checkbox is checked then input to b enabled/ input to be disabled if checkbox is false

Comment: i was able to do till here, how to proceed further,? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmhwjy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: i combined both of your answers and was able to do till here, thanks a lot

Comment: could you please help me to solve it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60360555/how-to-bind-array-of-ojects-to-formgroup-and-formarray-using-angular8?noredirect=1#comment106775614_60360555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the boolValue formcontrol, use this:

```
boolValue: this.FB.control({
    disabled: !x.boolValue,
    value: x.boolValue,
})
```

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

You can check it here

Comment: i have done upto here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmhwjy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: thanks for response, could you please help me out to proceed further?

Comment: could you please help me with this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60360555/how-to-bind-array-of-ojects-to-formgroup-and-formarray-using-angular8?noredirect=1#comment106775614_60360555

Comment: i combined 2 answers and was able to solve my issue thanks to both